# How to open contextMenu below the clicked element always?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I am trying to open a `contextMenu` on click of an element and I want it to be opened below the element always while it does not.

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.FlagsContexMenu',
    trigger: 'left',
     position: function (opt, x, y) {
        opt.$menu.position({
            my: 'right top',
            at: 'right bottom',
            of: opt.$trigger
         });
    }
});
```

I need it to open it as follow:-

[image]

While some times if scroll bar of a web page will be at the end then depending on the position of a scroll bar of a web page it open up as follow:

[image]

How may I achieve the first result regardless the position of a scroll bar of a web page ?

Comment: It might be helpfull to tell us which jQuery plugin you're using for this. When I check the official jQuery [.contextmenu()](https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/) docs, I'm fairly sure this is not what you're using.

Comment: @icecub I am using this one `http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html`

Comment: Seems you have somehow mixed the `position` and `determinePosition` options there. Take a closer look at the examples.